# Amending form of Array in Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

Im hoping somebody can help.

I have an array being returned by a call to a Google spreadsheet that returns like this:

```
{"2014 week"=>"01", "Weekly reach"=>"2.93"}
{"2014 week"=>"02", "Weekly reach"=>"3.37"}
{"2014 week"=>"03", "Weekly reach"=>"3.24"}
{"2014 week"=>"04", "Weekly reach"=>"2.39"}
{"2014 week"=>"05", "Weekly reach"=>"2.96"}
{"2014 week"=>"06", "Weekly reach"=>"6.31"}
{"2014 week"=>"07", "Weekly reach"=>"9.11"}
{"2014 week"=>"08", "Weekly reach"=>"8.59"}
{"2014 week"=>"09", "Weekly reach"=>"2.11"}
{"2014 week"=>"10", "Weekly reach"=>"2.24"}
{"2014 week"=>"11", "Weekly reach"=>"1.88"}
{"2014 week"=>"12", "Weekly reach"=>"2"}
{"2014 week"=>"13", "Weekly reach"=>"3"}
{"2014 week"=>"14", "Weekly reach"=>"2"}
{"2014 week"=>"15", "Weekly reach"=>"2"}
{"2014 week"=>"16", "Weekly reach"=>"3"}
```

Essentially, I want to amend this array in to the form:

> result = [{x:1, y: 2.93}, {x:2, y:3.37}, {x:3, y:3.24}...]

Due to my *noob* status in Ruby I'm struggling but believe the solution lies in **arr.map!**, a function that if I truly understood wouldn't require this question! Any help would be hugely appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`map` returns array consisting of the result of block evaluation for each element. So you should have:

```
result = array.map do |data|
  {
    x: data['2014 week'],
    y: data['reach']
  }
end
```

Comment: Apologies if I'm misunderstanding, but taking it wholesale (with changes to variables to suit code) I'm returning a completely blank array. Any ideas? In fact, using puts results.class actually return 'NilClass' as many times as there was values in the original array.

Comment: @MattVisser you should write what exactly you're trying to do step by step in question.

Comment: I've reviewed it with @dax comments below and found it is converting. I've rewritten the question a tad, could you guys possibly advise on converting the '=>' to : ?

Comment: @MattVisser I don't understand converting `=>` to `:` part?

Comment: It's due to the syntax required for the value to be passed correctly to a graph mapping function. Rather than rewriting the graph mapper, I'd rather provide the data as it expects if that makes sense? The exact form is in the second quote. Thanks for all your help so far.

Comment: this is just a different form of writing a hash:  `x: 1` is the same as `:x => 1`

Comment: if you're looking to graph the result of the data you're getting here, maybe you're using a jquery library?  in which case you probably need to convert this result to JSON.  see [ruby json](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html)

Comment: Thanks for the help both. I'll be honest, I've managed to get the output converted using .to_json, however, now I am getting results in the form - {"x":"value", "y":"value"}. My grapher cant accept the value unless in the form {x:value,y:value}. Any ideas? The json seems to have converted it to a string...

Answer (score 0):

Marek Lipka is right - I remember when I couldn't figure out map, though, so here's a more thorough explanation.

his answer is equivalent to this code, assuming `array` is defined like this:

```
array = [
  {"2014 week"=>"01", "Weekly reach"=>"2.93"},
  {"2014 week"=>"02", "Weekly reach"=>"3.37"},
  {"2014 week"=>"03", "Weekly reach"=>"3.24"},
  {"2014 week"=>"04", "Weekly reach"=>"2.39"},
  {"2014 week"=>"05", "Weekly reach"=>"2.96"},
  {"2014 week"=>"06", "Weekly reach"=>"6.31"},
  {"2014 week"=>"07", "Weekly reach"=>"9.11"},
  {"2014 week"=>"08", "Weekly reach"=>"8.59"},
  {"2014 week"=>"09", "Weekly reach"=>"2.11"},
  {"2014 week"=>"10", "Weekly reach"=>"2.24"},
  {"2014 week"=>"11", "Weekly reach"=>"1.88"},
  {"2014 week"=>"12", "Weekly reach"=>"2"},
  {"2014 week"=>"13", "Weekly reach"=>"3"},
  {"2014 week"=>"14", "Weekly reach"=>"2"},
  {"2014 week"=>"15", "Weekly reach"=>"2"},
  {"2014 week"=>"16", "Weekly reach"=>"3"},
]

result = []
array.map do |data|
  result << { x: data['2014 week'], y: data['reach'] }
end
return result
```

so `map` is doing exactly the same thing as each, but pushing the result of whatever it does into an array, so you don't have to.

Hope that helps to explain it, but tick Marek's answer - this is just too long for a comment